# The adaptation of script to using Interpolation in 3D

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d, scipy, interpolation

Here I need to interpolate my function in 3D. I already know how works interpolation but I didn't get how can I come to this interpolation function from my script. Actually, I already had few different trajectories which have a different number of points. That is why I need interpolation to decrease the number of points and make it equal. I tried to find an answer but couldn't find any.

So, here is my script:

```
C1 = np.add.accumulate(K)
C2 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
Kz = np.vstack((C2, C1));
x_new = Kz[:, 0];
y_new = Kz[:, 1];
z_new = Kz[:, 2];
```

## -----here I don't know how to come to the next step

```
def f(x_new, y_new, z_new):
    return 2 * x_new ** 3 + 3 * y_new ** 2 - z_new

x_new = np.linspace(1, 940, 200)
y_new = np.linspace(940, 1568, 200)
z_new = np.linspace(1568, 2195, 200)
data = f(*np.meshgrid(x_new, y_new, z_new, indexing='ij', sparse=True))
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x_new, y_new, z_new), data)
pts = np.array([[10, 950, 1600], [930, 1550, 2150]])
my_interpolating_function(pts)
```

Thank you.

Comment: So your code is running and you're trying to understand what it is doing? Then maybe you should post a [mcve]

Comment: No, it s not running and I know what I m trying to do. I try to decrease the number of steps in trajectory. For example, it was 2195 and I try to make it as 600. For this case, I m using Interpolation. So, I implement it but how to achieve again this 600 steps? this was the question.

Comment: What is a trajectory in your application? What's shown in your two code blocks? Are you trying to adapt the second (working) code to your application in the first block? What is the variable  `K`?

Comment: I guess, that it doesn't matter what is K. It is some array with dimensions 2195x3. So, in x_new, y_new and z_new I divided this K to free different access. After I wanna put those values to  
x_new = np.linspace(min.x_new(), max.x_new(), 200)
y_new = np.linspace(min.y_new(), max.y_new(), 200)
z_new = np.linspace(min.z_new(), max.z_new(), 200)
data = f(*np.meshgrid(x_new, y_new, z_new, indexing='ij', sparse=True))
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x_new, y_new, z_new), data)
mb smth like that and after all of this interpolation I wanna receive those new x,y, z again.

Comment: If you expect people to help, I guess you have to make the question clearer. Especially what the two code blocks above are there fore. For example you define the variables `x_new`, `y_new` and `z_new` twice. In fact, the second block in itself is working fine. Please be aware that you can also edit your original question to be more detailed.